# Enabling code completition in Atmel Studio 6

Tags: visual-studio, ide, intellisense, code-completion, atmel

I'm looking for autocomplete feature in Atmel's IDE Atmel Studio 6. As it is based on Visual Studio, there should be IntelliSense, but I can only find the menu entry "Intellisense" under "Edit", which has no effect at all. I'm programming in C.

Is there a way to provide autocompletition like in NetBeans (eg. Boxes that automatically pop up while typing)?

**Edit:** I do not mean autocomletition "wh" -> "while" but completing variables, function names, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atmel Studio 6 by default ships the Visual Assist (VA) which comprehensively provides intellisense support for C/C++ languague. You can check if VA is properly installed with Atmel Studio from the "Extensions manager" (Tools -> Extension Manager -> Installed Extensions" menu"). If it is not available you can downloand it from "Available Extensions" tab in Extension Manag

Comment: Just reinstalled IDE completely - fortunately all settings and projects were retained. Now I can see the extension in extension manager and everything is working fine :)